# Problema al guardar con JPA

Tags: java, netbeans, hibernate, jpa

Estoy tratando de  probar un método que he creado para guardar en una base de datos usando JPA, es el siguiente:

Mediante la siguiente clase:

```
public class Prueba {
  UsuarioImpls usuarioIm= new UsuarioImpls();
  public void guardaUsuario(){
    String nombre= "David";
    String apellido= "djsfla";
    String email= "sldk@lfsk.com";
    String pass= "sdkl";
    int tar= 152;

    usuarioIm.guardar(new Usuario(nombre, apellido, email, pass, tar));
  }

  public static void main(String[] args){
    Prueba p= new Prueba();
    p.guardaUsuario();
  }
}
```

El anterior método **guardarUsuario** utiliza a otro método que está implementado en esta otra clase:

```
public class UsuarioImpls implements UsuarioDAO, Serializable{

EntityManagerFactory emf= Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Tienda_V4.2PU");
EntityManager em= emf.createEntityManager();

@Override
public void guardar(Usuario usuario) {
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.persist(usuario);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
}
}
```

Y esta es la interfaz que lo contiene:

```
public interface UsuarioDAO<Usuario>{
void guardar(Usuario usuario);
}
```

La Clase entity a la que hace alusión la interfaz es esta:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "usuario")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "Usuario.findAll", query = "SELECT u FROM Usuario u")
, @NamedQuery(name = "Usuario.findById", query = "SELECT u FROM Usuario u WHERE u.id = :id")
, @NamedQuery(name = "Usuario.findByFecha", query = "SELECT u FROM Usuario u WHERE u.fecha = :fecha")
, @NamedQuery(name = "Usuario.findByNombre", query = "SELECT u FROM Usuario u WHERE u.nombre = :nombre")
, @NamedQuery(name = "Usuario.findByApellido", query = "SELECT u FROM Usuario u WHERE u.apellido = :apellido")
, @NamedQuery(name = "Usuario.findByEmail", query = "SELECT u FROM Usuario u WHERE u.email = :email")
, @NamedQuery(name = "Usuario.findByPassword", query = "SELECT u FROM Usuario u WHERE u.password = :password")
, @NamedQuery(name = "Usuario.findByTarjeta", query = "SELECT u FROM Usuario u WHERE u.tarjeta = :tarjeta")})
public class Usuario implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "ID")
private Integer id;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "FECHA")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date fecha;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "NOMBRE")
private String nombre;
@Column(name = "APELLIDO")
private String apellido;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "EMAIL")
private String email;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "PASSWORD")
private String password;
@Column(name = "TARJETA")
private Integer tarjeta;

public Usuario() {
}

public Usuario(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Usuario(Integer id, Date fecha, String nombre, String email, String password) {
    this.id = id;
    this.fecha = fecha;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
}

public Usuario(String nombre, String apellido, String email, String password, Integer tarjeta) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.apellido = apellido;
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
    this.tarjeta = tarjeta;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Date getFecha() {
    return fecha;
}

public void setFecha(Date fecha) {
    this.fecha = fecha;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public String getApellido() {
    return apellido;
}

public void setApellido(String apellido) {
    this.apellido = apellido;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public Integer getTarjeta() {
    return tarjeta;
}

public void setTarjeta(Integer tarjeta) {
    this.tarjeta = tarjeta;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
    if (!(object instanceof Usuario)) {
        return false;
    }
    Usuario other = (Usuario) object;
    if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "com.tienda.modelo.entities.Usuario[ id=" + id + " ]";
}

}
```

Al tratar de guardar en la base de datos el **StackTrace** me muestra el siguiente error el:

> WARN: HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead.
>   Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named Tienda_V4.2PU
>       at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:61)
>       at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
>       at com.tienda.dao.implement.UsuarioImpls.(UsuarioImpls.java:14)
>       at com.tienda.dao.implement.Prueba.(Prueba.java:7)
>       at com.tienda.dao.implement.Prueba.main(Prueba.java:19)

Este es el Persistence:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence 
 http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="Tienda_V4.2PU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
<class>com.tienda.modelo.entities.Usuario</class>
<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
<properties>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tiendadb"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="itla"/>
  <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider"/>
</properties>
```

Ya he cambiado el **provider** del **persistence** a:

```
org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistence
```

Y no funciona, me sigue dando el mismo error del nombre del persistence

También he revisado las librerías y me he asegurado de tenerlas importadas así como de que el Persistence Unit esté en la carpeta META-INF:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con todo me da este error, pueden orientarme sobre él.

Comment: Esta la clase marcada como `@Entity`?

Comment: Cual dices tu, el Entity Usuario?, ya he actualizado la pregunta incluyéndolo, esta marcado como tal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El `stacktrace` le esta diciendo eso precisamente:

El `org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistence` esta **obsoleto** por favor utilice: `org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider` Intente con eso a ver si le funciona. Aunque igual son **`Warning`** mas no **`Error`**.

**EDIT**

En efecto, después de haber recreado la aplicación, el problema surge debido a la sintaxis errónea de `/META-INF/persistence.xml` y "mala" ubicación de éste archivo para Netbeans.

El archivo tal y como está en la pregunta es:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="Tienda_V4.2PU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
<class>com.tienda.modelo.entities.Usuario</class>
<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
<properties>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tiendadb"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="itla"/>
  <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider"/>
</properties>
```

**Puede que haya sido un `copy-paste` mal hecho** Pero, el `persistence.xml` debe ser:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="Tienda_V4.2PU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>    
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>           
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="itla"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tiendadb"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>        
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>                        
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**Esta solución es para Netbeans!** ya que @David tuvo problemas utilizando éste IDE y el problema sale de la configuración inicial.

Se supone que `persistence.xml` debe ir en `/META-INF/` y esa es la forma como lo tiene configurado. **PERO** éstos archios de configuración, Netbeans los pone en lugares diferentes, luego al utilizar `ANT` para el **build**, pone los archivos donde deben estar pero a partir del archivo `conf` que nosotros vemos en Netbeans así:

[image]

El `persistence.xml` debe estar en `/Configuration Files/` y no en `/META-INF/`.

Una vez hice éstas correcciones el programa funciona sin problema.

Comment: Si, cierto es un **`warning`** y me da el mismo error

Comment: Cómo tiene el persistence.xml ?

Comment: Ya actualicé la pregunta con el `persistence`

Comment: @DavidCalderon Qué pasa si cambia el `provider` a : `<provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>`  en el persistence.xml.

Comment: Lo mismo: `PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named Tienda_V4.2PU`

Comment: agregue ésto al persistence: `<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/><property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>` Es configuración propia de hibernate

Comment: Si no le funciona, intente con el hibernate.cfg.xml para ver si de ésta forma sí le funciona o si es problema de librerías

Comment: Te parece si continuamos hablando en el chat

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49695/discussion-between-david-calderon-and-esteban-rincon).